# Error using lazy import with components stored in dictionary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've been trying to figure it out for several hours now, but seems cant find a solution for it. I'm trying to use lazy import with `react-router-dom`, adding routes dynamically. Here:

```
const routes = [
    {name: 'home', pattern: '/'},
    {name: 'books', pattern: '/books'},
    {name: 'authors', pattern: '/authors'},
]

const components: { [key: string]: React.LazyExoticComponent<any> } = {
    'home': lazy(() => import('../home')),
    'books': lazy(() => import('../books')),
    'authors': lazy(() => import('../authors')),
};

const Demo = () => (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Routes>
            {routes.map(route => (
                <Route
                    key={route.name}
                    path={route.pattern}
                    element={components[route.name]}
                />
            ))}
        </Routes>
    </Suspense>
);
```

it produces the following error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, _payload, _init}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

NOTE: variable `routes` that I iterate through is working since I'm getting correct `name` and `pattern` for all 3 endpoints.

The same goes if I manually add `Route` for every endpoint with hardcoded `path` and pass lazy import to an element.

```
const Demo = () => (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={lazy(() => import('../home'))}
            <Route path="/books" element={lazy(() => import('../books'))}
            <Route path="/authors" element={lazy(() => import('../authors'))}
        </Routes>
    </Suspense>
);
```

The only way I managed to make it work is by assigning lazy import to a variable and then adding using it within `element` prop. But that is extra lines. Like this:

```
const Home = lazy(() => import('../home'))
const Books = lazy(() => import('../books'))
const Authors = lazy(() => import('../authors'))

const AppRouter = () => (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Statement />} />
            <Route path="/books" element={<Books />} />
            <Route path="/authors" element={<Authors />} />
        </Routes>
    </Suspense>
);
```

Is there a way to make it work with components being imported within a dictionary?

Comment: I think an example of `routes` would help.

Comment: @ChanYoun I've seen it, this one for example - `https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/lazy-loading` its the same as the last block of code in my post, but I'm looking for a way to initiate lazy imports within a dictionary.

Comment: I meant an example of the `routes` object.  I'm just trying to make sure you don't need to call `Object.entries(routes).map` ... instead of `routes.map` on line 10 of your first code block.

Comment: Oh, no. `route` object is just a simple array of objects. In the second example I don't use it but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Calling `React.createElement(components[route.name], {})` probably would fix the compilation issue, but since you're mapping over every route, that might also break the lazy importing and cause every element to be imported. Not sure how the implementation of createElement works with lazy imports